If the variance converges to zero, when do we have almost sure convergence
We have that $\mathbf{E}(X_n)=c$ where c is a positive constant and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathtt{Var}(X_n)  =0$. Then
$$ X_n \rightarrow c \quad  \mbox{in probability as} \quad  n \rightarrow \infty. $$
If it is also known that $X_n$ is bounded, can one show that $X_n$ approaches $c$ almost surely, and if so why, or is there a counter-example?

No.  Consider $X_n \in \{0,1\}$, therefore bounded, and the sequence of probabilities $P_n(X_n = 1) = 1/n$ (and therefore $P_n(X_n = 0) = 1 - 1/n$.)  Clearly $X_n \to 0$ in probability, but Borel-Cantelli tells us that $X_n$ does not converge almost surely to $0$, as we expect to see infinitely many $1$ values over the sequence.
Edit:  I overlooked the constraint of $\mathrm{E}(X_n) = c$, but the above example can easily be extended to cover it.
Consider $X_n \in \{0,1,2\}$, with the sequence of probabilities $P_n(X_n = 0) = P_n(X_n = 2) = 1/n$.  $\mathrm{E}(X_n) = 1 \;\forall\;n$, so the constraint on the expected value is satisfied.  Clearly $X_n \to 1$ in probability, but Borel-Cantelli still tells us that we don't get almost sure convergence of $X_n$ to $1$.

Thank you for the example @jbowman. Is there also an example where $\mathbf{E}(X_n)$ is a constant for all $n$?

Ah, I overlooked that part of the question :(. But you can just symmetrize the above example; work with ${0,1,2}$ with mean $1$, for example.

To show $\{X_n\}$ converges to $c$ almost surely, one can add the extra condition that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathrm{Var}(X_n)<\infty \tag{*}\label 1$$
which can be satisfied by, for example, if $\mathrm{Var}(X_n)=O(2^{-n})$.
In other words, we need the variance to converge fast enough in order to upgrade convergence in probability to that almost surely. Formally, we have the following proposition, which is a direct result of Borel–Cantelli lemma and Chebyshev's inequality.
Proposition 1. Consider a sequence of random variables $\{X_n\}$ satisfying $EX_n=c$ and $\eqref 1$. Then, we have $X_n \to \mu$ almost surely as $n\to \infty$.
Proof. Using the Chebyshev's inequality, we have (for any $\epsilon>0$),
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(|X_n-c|>\epsilon)\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{Var}(X_n)}{\epsilon^2}<\infty$$
Therefore, using the Borel–Cantelli lemma (Thm. 7.5 of here), we conclude $X_n\to c$ almost surely.
